# "Server x timed out" during MongoDB aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, alpine-linux

I have a script that periodically runs aggregation on a mongodb collection. As the dataset has grown, the amount of time it takes to aggregate has also grown. My aggregation script has recently stopped working consistently, and the error logs show: 

`error: { [MongoError: server <x> timed out]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'server <x> timed out' }`

I've tried debugging this, and the only pattern I can find is that this timeout seems to only occur when the aggregation takes longer than 2 minutes (it times out right around 2m). Does anyone have additional debugging tips for this? The 2-minute thing is giving me the impression that I just need to configure some timeout somewhere but I can't figure out where or if i'm just falling into a red-herring trap.

About the system configuration: This aggregation script is a node.js (v5.9.1) application running in an alpine-based docker (v1.9.1) container. It uses the `mongodb` node driver (v2.1.19). Single mongodb server (though this is also happening in a separate environment with a replSet) running mongod (v3.2.6)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the same problem for logs time aggregation. I think I have the solution for you.

I found that the option `socketTimeoutMS` is responsible for that.
Check your mongo_client.js default `socketTimeoutMS` value. For me it was `2min`. Mongodb module version 2.1.18.

So just add this option into your url :

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/test?maxPoolSize=2&socketTimeoutMS=60000
```

It will set `timeout` to 10 mins. That does the trick for me.