# MongoDB timeout issue (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an application in Node.JS which basically retrieves a snapshot of data from a WebAPI each 30 minutes.
When I try to interrogate the database by using an aggregate query, the app triggers an error related to timeout (MongoError: connection 1 to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out). From my logs I see that it's exactly 30 seconds.
The aggregate query is something like this:

```
collection.aggregate([{
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    country: "$country",
                    user: "$user"
                }
            }
        }]).
```

I tested the query on a different client (but the same database) and it takes aprox 60 seconds for 25.000.000 records. My assumption is that there is a timeout parameter with the value of 30 seconds that blocks my application from finish the query.
Can someone tell me how can I set this parameter up in Node.JS? I'm using 'mongodb' js library and my host machine is Windows.

Since this is a personal project I wanted to investigate how can I use MongoDB instead of a more traditional solution, such as Oracle or MySQL, but this might be a deal breaker since analytics is a core part of the entire application.

Comment: "the app triggers an error related to timeout" sounds a bit vague. Exactly how does this error look like? Where does it come from?

Comment: the error is this: MongoError: connection 1 to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out

Answer (score 9):

I found a solution in this answer: ["Server x timed out" during MongoDB aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899216/server-x-timed-out-during-mongodb-aggregation).

Basically, the connection string looks like this now:

```
this.server = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test?socketTimeoutMS=90000';
```

The `socketTimeoutMS` did the trick and I don't get anymore the connection timeout error.

Answer (score 2):

in your mongo connect

```
let options = {    
    server: {    
      auto_reconnect: true,    
      socketOptions: {

        keepAlive: 1,    
        connectTimeoutMS: 60000,    
        socketTimeoutMS: 60000,    
      }    
    },    
    replset: {    
      auto_reconnect: true,    
      socketOptions: {    
        keepAlive: 1,    
        connectTimeoutMS: 60000,    
       socketTimeoutMS: 60000,    
      }    
   }

  }

  Mongoose.connect(url, options);
```

Comment: This method is now deprecated, when you use it you now have: `the server/replset/mongos options are deprecated, all their options are supported at the top level of the options object`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the correct option (if you are using MongoClient) is to use `serverSelectionTimeoutMS` instead. You can do it so like follows:

```
const client = new MongoClient(mongoUrl, {
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 1000, useUnifiedTopology: true
})
```

I haven't tested but you can find [more details here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/connect-timeout-and-execution-timeout-in-nodejs-driver/2129). You may also find some luck with `connectTimeoutMS` and `maxTimeMS`.

Comment: i dont see that 'serverSelectionTimeoutMS' option in https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html

Comment: That's odd... Although you can find It here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/connection-options/

Comment: oh, maybe that one from github.io is old doc 