# Meteor Method/Call Timed Out after 30 seconds

Tags: meteor

I am running into an issue with a very complex aggregate on a slow database setup that I have running.

Sometimes if it is complex enough it takes over 30 seconds, and I get:

```
Exception while invoking method 'methodName' MongoError: connection 3 to 'IP.IP.IP.IP' timed out
 at Object.Future.wait
```

I know that it's not great to have something that takes over 30 seconds but that's what I'm working with. Is there any way to set the meteor call to wait for longer than 30 seconds before timing out?

Comment: Unless you are dealing with tens of millions of documents, you could probably make your script way more efficient. Why don't you post the code for it and then maybe we can help you speed it up?

Comment: I am dealing with tens of millions of documents, with $facet, $lookup and several other intensive operations.

Comment: Fair enough - 30 + seconds still seems like a huge amount of time. Have you added indexes to the fields you are querying?

Comment: Do you have `this.unblock` in your method?

Comment: Michel - how does this.unblock stop the method from timing out? I haven't used it before but it looks like it would be used if I had other things going on and didn't want to lock up the rest of the app with one method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this after digging in the problem a bit more. In my connection to my meteor app when I specify the url I needed to add a this to my mongo url:

```
socketTimeoutMS=XXXXX
```

My url now looks like:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName?socketTimeoutMS=45000 meteor
```

This thread got me in the right direction:
["Server x timed out" during MongoDB aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899216/server-x-timed-out-during-mongodb-aggregation)

I had also tried `.noCursorTimeout()` at the end of my aggregate on guess, that did nothing.